# Python - Replacing Values Leading Up To 1s in an Array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Pretend I have a pandas Series that consists of 0s and 1s, but this can work with numpy arrays or any iterable. I would like to create a formula that would take an array and an input n and then return a new series that contains 1s at the nth indices leading up to every time that there is at least a single 1 in the original series. Here is an example:

```
array = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])

> preceding_indices_function(array, 2)
np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

For each time there is a 1 in the input array, the two indices preceding it are filled in with 1 regardless of whether there is a 0 or 1 in that index in the original array.

I would really appreciate some help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use a convolution with [`np.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html):

```
N = 2

# craft a custom kernel
kernel = np.ones(2*N+1)
kernel[-N:] = 0
# array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0])

out = (np.convolve(array, kernel, mode='same') != 0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: This is great. As a follow up, how would I create a function that returns an array that denotes m 1s after n indices following the first 1 in the input array? As if I wanted to create a lagging indicator of a series of 0s and 1s that shows the 3 periods following the first 1 in every set of 1s in an array?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you don't want to use `numpy`, mozway's `transpose` is the best solution.

But since several iterations have been given, I add my itertools based solution

```py
[a or b or c for a,b,c in itertools.zip_longest(array, array[1:], array[2:], fillvalue=0)]
```

`zip_longest` is the same as classical `zip`, but if the iterators have different "lengths", the number of iteration is the one of the longest, and finished iterators will return `None`. Unless you add a `fillvalue` parameter to `zip_longest`.

So, here `itertools.zip_longest(array, array[1:], array[2:], fillvalue=0)` gives a sequence of triplets (a,b,c), of 3 subsequent elements (a being the current element, b the next, c the one after, b and c being 0 if there isn't any next element or element after the next).

So from there, a simple comprehension build a list of `[a or b or c]` that is 1 if a, or b or c is 1, 0 else.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])

array = np.array([a or array[idx+1] or array[idx+2] for idx, a in enumerate(array[:-2])] + [array[-2] or array[-1]] + [array[-1]])
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works?

Answer (score -1):

this function works if a is a list, should work with other iterables as well:

```
def preceding_indices_function(array, n):
  for i in range(len(a)):
    if array[i] == 1:
      for j in range(n):
        if i-j-1 >= 0:
          array[i-j-1] = 1
  return array
```

Answer (score -1):

I got a solution that is similar to the other one but slightly simpler in my opinion:

```
>>> [1 if (array[i+1] == 1 or array[i+2] == 1) else x for i,x in enumerate(array) if i < len(array) - 2]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```